# Error: The LINQ expression node type 'ArrayIndex' is not supported in LINQ to Entities

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

Working on MVC5 app. I have a string array defined as....

```
string[] myArray;
```

It has 3 items in it....

```
{string[3]}
   [0]: "a411d1bc-21f7-4e4d-a4d3-4dd36e1b319f"
   [1]: "ef4e3655-fa6f-4dfc-b2d4-178ac5914f0b"
   [2]: "d75a98c5-a829-43c5-b2cf-d50be1189a05"
```

These are actually the primary keys for records in the AspNetUser table. I want to execute an EF WHERE clause using the array items in multiple "WHERE". (So basically I want to retrieve these 3 users from the AspNetUser table.) Here's my code so far...

```
IQueryable<Event> events = db.Events;

if (myArray != null)
{
    events = events.Include(a => a.AspNetUser);

    for(int i = 0; i <= myArray.Length-1; i++)
    {
        events = events.Where(u => u.AspNetUser.Id == myArray[i].ToString());
    }
}
```

So, as you can see, I'm basically looping thru the array (that contains all the PK) and using it in my WHERE clause.

But, right when I hit the first .WHERE line in the loop I'm getting this error:

> The LINQ expression node type 'ArrayIndex' is not supported in LINQ to Entities.

What am I doing wrong here? Is there a better approach?

Finally, for a dynamic scenario such as I described, **how can I used OR statements rather than an AND commands for the where?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Under normal circumstances, when performing an operation like a `Where` in EntityFramework, it isn't actually executed in memory like when you operate on an enumerable (like a List). Instead, it converted into SQL which is then executed by the Db provider. This means that doing certain things, such as using extension methods on objects or, in your case, getting elements from arrays by index is not an option, as the converter cannot turn such things into SQL.

To fix your **existing code**, you need to modify your for loop like so:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= myArray.Length-1; i++)
{
    var temp = myArray[i].ToString();
    events = events.Where(u => u.AspNetUser.Id == temp);
}
```

Moving the array operation outside of the query allows EntityFramework to convert it into SQL properly.

A **better approach** to doing what you want would be the following:

```
var result = events.Where(u => myArray.Contains(u.AspNetUser.Id));
```

Comment: Thanks @stybl . As I loop, how can I do similar to an OR clause (contains/in), rather than a bunch of ANDs?

Comment: @WebDevGuy2 You'll have to explain what you mean a bit more. Do you just want one match?

Comment: I think you answered it with your Contains line above. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you need them in the same order, then you can do this:

```
IQueryable<Event> events = db.Events;

if (myArray != null)
{
    events = events
      .Include(a => a.AspNetUser)
      .Where(a=> myArray.Contains(a.AspNetUser.Id))
      .ToList()
      .OrderBy(a=>myArray.IndexOf(a.AspNetUser.Id));
}
```

If you don't care if they are in the same order, then you can do this:

```
IQueryable<Event> events = db.Events;

if (myArray != null)
{
    events = events
      .Include(a => a.AspNetUser)
      .Where(a=> myArray.Contains(a.AspNetUser.Id));
}
```

You might need to to convert your string array to a guid array if the Id is a guid (You might not).  If so, then just do this:

```
var myGuidArray = myArray
  .Select(a=> Guid.Parse(a))
  .ToArray();
```

Then change the above queries to reference myGuidArray instead of myArray.

Comment: Thanks. But, isn't this searching where myArray Contains xyz? I want to search AspNetUser table for where Id Contains the elements in myArray.

Comment: Yes, it is searching the entire AspNetUser table for users that are contained within the myArray array.  So if you have in your user table, ids A,B,C,D, and E, and myArray has B, C, and D, then the result will be the users that have an ID of B, C, or D (three users).

Comment: Also, if the only reason why you are including AspNetUser is to filter (You don't actually want or need the data in the AspNetUser table), then you can skip the .Include completely.  EF will still filter correctly and return only the records that match, and will be much faster.

Comment: Thanks @RobertMcKee. I have a username, firstname, lastname fields in aspnetuser table so I want to reference these. So I need it for this case. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are trying to access your array inside a Linq to SQL expression and it isn't recognized. You just need to pull out `myArray[i]` and set it to a variable and then use the variable:

```
var myVariable = myArray[i].ToString();
events = events.Where(u => u.AspNetUser.Id == myVariable);
```

Basically the `.Where` is taking what you have and trying to turn it into a SQL query but it doesn't know how to turn `myArray[i]` into SQL.

Comment: Downvoted because this only returns a single record, not all 3.