# 'ArrayIndex' is not supported in LINQ to Entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

'ArrayIndex' is not supported in LINQ to Entities.

```
 var result = uow.Repository<T_Tenant_Sub_PortalSetting>().Search(x => x.StudentPortalUrl.Split('/')[0].ToString() == filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.Host 
            && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.StudentPortalUrl.Split('/')[1].ToString())) ? true : x.StudentPortalUrl.Split('/')[1].ToString() == WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["VirtualDirectoryName"])
            .IncludeEntity(x => x.T_Tenant_Sub).AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45681514/error-the-linq-expression-node-type-arrayindex-is-not-supported-in-linq-to-en

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: The LINQ expression node type 'ArrayIndex' is not supported in LINQ to Entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45681514/error-the-linq-expression-node-type-arrayindex-is-not-supported-in-linq-to-en)

Comment: think not duplicate. my problem is ..split string from database

Comment: You are using `[1]` on the result of `Split` - which is an array you are indexing. Hence `ArrayIndex` not supported.

Answer (score 0):

1. you can fetch all students {id,url} in memory,then you can use split on url.
2. create an array of your entity key type (ex:int[] if your id is int)after doing your checks depend on host and ... .
3. then you can send the array to database for fetching selected rows

---

```
//imagine this list is my entities IDbSet<...>
List<MyClass> myClasses = new List<MyClass>();

//you can read all entities {id,url} in RAM
Dictionary<int, string> keyValues = 
                new Dictionary<int, string>();


myClasses
.Where(x => true/*some conditions here*/)
.Select(x => new { x.Id, x.Url })
.ToList()//here data fetched from db
.ForEach(x => keyValues.Add(x.Id, x.Url));

//now you can use split

int[] SelectedIds = keyValues
                .Where(x => x.Value.Split('/')[0] == "host"
                        /*&& another conditions here*/)
                .Select(x=>x.Key)
                .ToArray();

//now you can pass an array to db for fetching data

//as dbset
myClasses
    .Where(x => 
        SelectedIds.Contains(x.Id));

    int[] SelectedIds = keyValues.Where(x => x.Value.Split('/')[0] == "host"/*&& another conditions here*/)
        .Select(x=>x.Key)
        .ToArray();

    //now you can pass an array to db for fetching data

    //as dbset
    myClasses.Where(x => SelectedIds.Contains(x.Id));
```